# Reducing redundant code for a PyQt application

Tags: python, class, methods, pyqt, signals-slots

I'm not yet articulate enough to be specific with my title but that's basically the problem. I'm making a QGIS plugin with PyQt.

**SCRIPT**

```
class CreateSomething(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(CreateSomething, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Only select polygon layers in the layer combo box
        self.cmbLyrSelect.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PolygonLayer)
        # Emits a signal and connects to a function when layer is changed    
        self.cmbLyrSelect.layerChanged.connect(self.getLayerInfo)  

    # Function to get layer info if layer changed
    def getLayerInfo(self):
        # Selected/current layer in the combo box  
        currLyr = self.cmbLyrSelect.currentLayer()
        # Gets layer centroid
        lyrLoc = self.cmbLyrSelect.currentLayer().sourceExtent().center().toString(3)
        # Writes layer centroid to line edit
        self.linLyrLoc.setText(str(lyrLoc))
        # Populates combo box with fields of current layer
        self.cmbLyrFields.setLayer(currLyr)
```

If the plugin is opened the first time, it will not have the necessary widgets filled because the `cmbLyrSelect` widget only emits a signal when the user changes a layer.

**First open**

[image]

**If layer is changed**

[image]

**WORKAROUND** - duplicate the code in the `getLayerInfo` method to the `__init__` method so that the widgets are filled up once the plugin starts.

```
class CreateSomething(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            """Constructor."""
            super(CreateSomething, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setupUi(self)

            self.cmbLyrSelect.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PolygonLayer)    
            self.cmbLyrSelect.layerChanged.connect(self.getLayerInfo)    
            currLyr = self.cmbLyrSelect.currentLayer()
            lyrLoc = self.cmbLyrSelect.currentLayer().sourceExtent().center().toString(3)
            self.linLyrLoc.setText(str(lyrLoc))
            self.cmbLyrFields.setLayer(currLyr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `getLayerInfo` once explicitly in `__init__` before registering the LayerChanged callback:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    """Constructor."""
    super(CreateSomething, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    # Only select polygon layers in the layer combo box
    self.cmbLyrSelect.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PolygonLayer)
    # Explicitly get layer info on init
    self.getLayerInfo()
    # Emits a signal and connects to a function when layer is changed    
    self.cmbLyrSelect.layerChanged.connect(self.getLayerInfo)
```